# center aligning a table

Tags: html, css

how do you center align a table in the middle of the page using css. This is what I have http://jsfiddle.net/m5uEr/

```
<div style="text-align: center; border-style:solid;">
    <table style="border-style:solid;">
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You surely not the first one in the world trying to do so!

Comment: Did you even try to find the answer yourself ?

Comment: yeah for some reason margin-left + margin-right auto doesn't seem to work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center-align an HTML child table within a parent table via CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032709/how-to-center-align-an-html-child-table-within-a-parent-table-via-css)

Answer (score 2):

```
table.center {
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
  }

<table style="border-style:solid;" class="center">
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5uEr/1/)

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=center%20align%20table%20css&oq=center%20align%20table%20css&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j62l2j59.5013&sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) found it for me with this text: *"center align table css"*

Answer (score 1):

Set a width on your table and set

```
margin:auto
```

Answer (score 1):

css wasn't working so I did a `<table align="center">`

this is on IE8

Answer (score 1):

Did you put margin-left:auto, margin-right:auto in the properties of the div?

That is easy to do.

Those properties should belong in table

```
<div style="text-align: center; border-style:solid;">
    <table style="border-style:solid; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; ">
        <tr>
            <td>tdddest</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>​
```